# Get the universal app (windows phone) information

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

Is there a way to extract the same information displayed in the Settings|About in a Windows Phone 8.1 (WINRT) Universal App?

I've been googling for a while but to no avail, well I'm wondering if it's because I'm running this in the emulator.

I'm interested in checking what information I can extract from the device simply from a curiosity point of view, but I really would like to be able to extract the Name (as displayed as the first line below the "Phone Information" title).

I've tried the following:

```
Windows.System.UserProfile.UserInformation.GetFirstNameAsync();
Windows.System.UserProfile.UserInformation.GetFirstNameAsync();
Windows.System.UserProfile.UserInformation.GetDisplayNameAsync();
...
```

I've also tried the following:

```
Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.
```

and loop through all the returned items (i.e. 113) but it didn't provide anything really related to the About|Setting|User Information.

I ran the above in my emulator and directly on my phone but all the UserInformation functions are returning me blank values.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really get these (esp. on the phone). If you check the related MSDN pages you can see:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.userprofile.userinformation.aspx - for example the `GetLastName` method remarks contain: "Access to the user's last name can be blocked by privacy settings (for example, if the UserInformation::NameAccessAllowed property is false). If access is blocked, this method returns an empty string."

Also the `DeviceInformation` class is more for finding attached devices to the PC (eg.: like printer helper apps): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformation

Comment: What would be the best way to identify a mobile? I'm doing this for auditing purpose where I want to log what "device" has logged in or attempted to login? Ideally, I wanted to display the user name associated with the device but if there's another way, I don't mind checking it out i.e. IP Address, IMEI, Other?

Comment: You can generate a unique hardware ID from this: Windows.System.Profile.HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken(null)

Comment: As mentioned, this would be for auditing purpose, so having an IMEI or a unique hardware ID would be very little use to me. It may be the only solution but unless a user has previously registered his/her user under that specific hardware key, we won't be able to tell who tried to login or not, especially if login failed. Any other suggestions? Thanks.